Getting bin/sf: No such file or directory error after uninstalling sfdx
I was following the salesforce document's guide to uninstall sfdx first then install sf commands. Then I encountered this error:

/Users/shiy2/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sf: line 16:
/Users/shiy2/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/../7.209.6-8ba3197/bin/sf:
No such file or directory

Till now I have tried many ways as I can find on the internet but none of them worked for me. I even tried with uninstall/reinstall using: npm uninstall @salesforce/cli --global and npm install @salesforce/cli --global but it is still not working. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I assume you are on macOS, initially installed a *.pkg file coming with version 7.209.6-8ba3197 and have got this exact same error ever since, executing any sf commands?! Do you see any installed version of sf anywhere below /Users/shiy2/.local/share/sfdx/client/? If I were you, I'd take utter care not to get a mix of npm and OS specific installation of sf (e.g. not to do an npm uninstall on a *.pkg installation).

@FelixvanHove Yes, I am using macOS. I installed sfdx several years ago so I can't actually remember in which approach I installed the cli. And I can see both sf and sfdx folder under  /Users/shiy2/.local/share/ and under bin folder I can see commands both there. So for now, is there any way I can fix this?

This seems a known problem. Read further down for instructions regarding sf instead of sfdx. Are you sure you've cleaned up 100% according to official recommendations? The version referred to from your sf is at least a year old.

Thanks for the recommendations. Yes, I used to be okay with my sf commands so I didn't update them. These two days I had a bit issue with my local admin access due to company policy and I am trying to walk my way out of these so haven't done those sudo commands yet. But I will do them and retry. Thanks again.
